# Intellisense not showing up. The selection object

Tags: vba

The intellisense is not showing up when I'm trying to use the selection object.

Can this be solved? I even tried to dim a selection object, same results.

E.g writing selection. does not result in any intellisense help...

Comment: Intellisense only works for objects that have been bound using Early Binding. Late binding will not bring up intellisense.

Comment: @PaulFrancis While it is true that IntelliSense requires early binding, the reason why `Selection` does not produce anything is because it is typed as `Object`, even though it is early binding.

Comment: @GSerg, I missed the part where the OP mentioned - `I even tried to dim a selection object`. I thought it was because of binding. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliSense cannot produce anything for `Application.Selection` because it is typed as `Object`.

The reason why it is typed as `Object` is that `Application.Selection` can return different types of objects depending on the current selection. It can be a `Range`, but it can also be a `Shape` or a `Chart`.

If you are sure your `Selection` is always a `Range`, declare a variable of the type `Range` and assign `Selection` to that, then use the variable.